# How to change LED color of AWS Alexa Echo or Echo Dot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

After some Google search I was not able to find. Is there a way to change the LED ring color of the AWS Echo or AWS Echo Dot? I always blue kind and I want to change it to a more contextual app color range.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Amazon does not provide a SDK endpoint to change the color of the LEDs of the Echo or the Echo Dot.

Comment: do you have any doc link about it please?